# What field of maths is this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have a simple function $f(n,x)$ which for some integer $x$ generates a unique rational number $f$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ - for argument's sake lets imagine it's $\frac{x^2}{5n}$.

Suppose I generate a set $F_x$ using $f$ as follows:

$F_x=\{f(n,x):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

So $F_1$ is the range of $f(n,1)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Now suppose I create a new set by using the entire range of $f$ as an input into $F$, instead of the number 1, so:

$F_{F_1}=\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N} f(n,F_1)$

Let's call this $F^2_1$.

Clearly this set can be regarded as an $n\times n$ matrix or set albeit with some possibly duplicate elements.

Now suppose I take the limit as $y\to\infty$ of $F^y_1$ and we might call this $F^{\infty}_1$.

It would seem logical that this be an $\lvert\mathbb{N}\rvert^{\lvert\mathbb{N}\rvert}$ matrix with some possibly repeated elements.

With a very superficial understanding of Galois theory I think I'm constructing some kind of ring or field here but I was wondering if anybody can clarify.

What I'm interested in, is the fact that Galois theory requires the introduction of irrational numbers, but by this system it would appear possible to divide the $rational$ numbers into rings connected according to their prime factors by means of reiteration of the function $f^n$ and I am wondering if this is a known system already - and if so what field of maths is it?

One aspect I am studying is the power of such a set to generate a covering for all the rational numbers.

Being self-taught I have a habit of reinventing the wheel.  I have the requirement to make use of this and I wanted to check before I start whether there is some system already which I may be able to make use of.

Comment: This looks to be more set theory than anything else.

Comment: Also, you should clarify your notation; what is $f(n,F_1)$? Is it $$f(n,F_1)= \{f(n,X) \mid x \in F_1\}?$$ Is $F_1^2$ meant to be a set of numbers, or is it a collection of sets of numbers?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm more inclined to make it a set of numbers rather than a collection of sets, as that's sufficient for my purposes.  If it helps to see how it's the "rational" equivalent of a field or rings, think of $f=(x+n/2)$ and you can see $F_1$ contains every $n/2\geq 1$, $F^{2}_1$ contains every $n/4$ including every $n/2$ and so on...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how does that make your set a ring? For me, what makes a ring a ring is the ability to add/multiply two elements and remain within the set

Comment: Actually, your construction (especially for the first function) is looking a bit like the [p-adic numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: Also, I think you'll like [this video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=XFDM1ip5HdU&ebc=ANyPxKqMv81WbV_zZVl1Ne7HLvZDTB1MJM9S49BWW33QSXwGLqjalAbsqH2zV5kFDFWcVQRQlBcTeZozm_hJYnW4EsnzmD4bpw) (on p-adics)

Comment: I guess it depends what the addition and multiplication operators are.  You can create a closed form that takes you from one element of $F$ to the next and that can be your "addition".  Then if you replace the $1$ with the limit as $y\to -\infty$ then you have an abelian group.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. Highly enthused about learning about p-adics.  At work at the moment so I'll have to look at the video later.